# The existence of a ball intersecting unbounded connected sets?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,d) $ be a metric space and let $\mathcal{C} $ be an arbitrary collection of unbounded and connected subsets of $X$ that are pairwise disjoint.
Prove or disprove: for all $x\in X $, there is an $r>0$ such the closed ball $B(x,r)$ intersects every elemet of $\mathcal {C} $.

This seems true for $\mathbb R^n$ from geometric intuition, but I have no proof for it.

EDIT: I realised thanks to the comments and answer that this problem is clear. I asked it without adding a very important condition on the sets in $\mathcal{C}$, is that they are also open. So $\mathcal C$ contains **open**, connected, unbounded subsets of $X$ that are pairwise disjoint.

Comment: It's not true even in $\mathbb{R}$. Take $C = \{1,2,3,4,\ldots \}= \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: The set you gave is not connected.

Comment: You said $\mathcal C$ was a collection of .... and connected sets. I think you need to rewrite your sentence. I actually cannot understand what you're thinking.

Comment: I edited the sentence.

Comment: Take $C$ to be an infinite family of distinct parallel lines, such that the minimum distance between any two lines is 1. Then each line is connected and unbounded, the lines are pairwise distinct, and clearly there is no closed ball intersecting every line.

Comment: @Joppy. Nice. Simpler than my answer.

Comment: @Joppy thanks for the answer but I edited the problem, I forced the subsets to also be open. Then lines won't work as a counter example.

Comment: Can't you just "thicken" the lines up then, to get a counterexample? Replace each line with a union of open balls of radius 1/3 about each point of the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X=\mathbb R^2$ with the usual (Cartesian) metric. Let $\{s_n: n\in \mathbb N\}\subset [0,2\pi)$ such that $n\ne m\implies s_n\ne s_m.$ Let $C(n)=\{(nr\cos s_n, nr\sin s_n):r\geq 1\}.$ The closure of any open ball intersects only finitely many members of $\{C(n):n\in \mathbb N\}.$

Answer to the modified Q, in which each member of $C$ is open:

Let $C(n)$ be as above and let $D=\{C(n):n\in \mathbb N\}.$ Each $C(n)$ is closed, and $D$ is a separated family. That is, $C(n)\cap Cl(\cup (D$ \ $C(n))=\phi$ for each $n.$

Let $E(1)=\cup_{x\in C(1)}B(x,r_x)$ where  $1/2>r_x>0

and $Cl(B(x,2r_x))\cap (\cup (D$ \ $C(1))=\phi.$

Let $E(n+1)=\cup_{x\in C(n+1)}B(x,r_x)$ where  $1/2>r_x>0$

and $Cl(B(x,2r_x))\cap (\cup (D$ \ $C(n+1))=\phi$

and also $Cl(B(x,2r_x))\cap (\cup_{j\leq n}Cl(E(j)))=\phi.$

Each $E(n)$ is open, non-empty, and connected, and $E(m)\cap E(n)=\phi$ when $m\ne n.$  But the closure of any open ball intersects only finitely many members of $\{E(n):n\in \mathbb N\}.$

Remarks. In a metric space, any separated family $F$ is completely separated. That is, if $\forall f\in F\;(f\cap Cl(\cup (F \ \{f\})=\phi$ then there exists a family $G$ of pair-wise disjoint open sets such  that (i) for each non-empty $f\in F$ there exists $g\in G$ with $f\subset G$, and such that (ii)  for each non-empty $g\in G$ there is a unique non-empty $f\in F$ with $f\subset G.$ (We call $G$ a complete separation of $F$.)

In the case where the space is $\mathbb R^n$ and each $f\in F$ is connected, we can arrange to have each $g\in G$ connected also. And when $O=(0,0)\not \in Cl(\cup F)$ we can also arrange for $\inf_{x\in g} d(x,O)\geq (1/2)\inf_{y\in f}d(y,O)$ whenever $g\in G, f\in F,$ and and $g\supset f \ne \phi.$

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I added a very important missing condition.

Comment: I have answered your new Q also.